# How to write unit test case for a method [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm a beginner in Angular. I'm trying hard to learn Typescript and now I've been told to write unit test cases in Jasmine and Karma for every `component` and `service` I create. I've watched many tutorials to learn *Unit testing in Angular*. I'm an intern, yesterday I raised a Pull request on which my tech lead has given the following comment.

[image]

Here is the code that I've written.

**filter-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import './filter-bar.component.scss';
import { SisenseService } from '../services/sinsense.service';
import { SisenseConfigService } from '../services/sinsense-config.service';
import { Dashboard, Widget } from 'src/app/shared/models/sisenseConfig';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter-bar',
    templateUrl: './filter-bar.component.html'
})
export class FilterBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  selectedMembersCount: number;
  dataUnavailable: boolean;

  constructor(
    public sisenseService: SisenseService,
    public sisenseConfigService: SisenseConfigService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataFromWidget();
  }

  getDataFromWidget() {
    this.sisenseService.getWidgetData(
    this.sisenseConfigService.getDashboardId(Dashboard.POPULATION),
    this.sisenseConfigService.getWidgetInfo(Dashboard.POPULATION, Widget.UNIQUE_LIVES).id,
      widgetData => {
        this.selectedMembersCount = widgetData.queryResult.value.data;
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      },
      () => {
        this.dataUnavailable = true;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the spec file that I've written:

**filter-bar.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FilterBarComponent } from './filter-bar.component';
import { SisenseFilterService } from '../services/sinsense-filter.service';
import { PopUpService } from '@wuitk6/angular/components/popup/popup.service';
import { SisenseService } from '../services/sinsense.service';
import { SisenseConfigService } from '../services/sinsense-config.service';

describe('FilterPanelComponent', () => {
    let component: FilterBarComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterBarComponent>;

    mockSisenseConfigService.getWidgetInfo.and.returnValue({ id: 'demo_ID' });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterBarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
});
```

And here's the service, (i don't know who has written this code):

**sisense-config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
...
import { ErrorService } from './error.service';

// This is to avoid compile errors in typescript.
// The real variable will be added when sisense.js is loaded
declare var Sisense: any;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SisenseConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private errorService: ErrorService) {}

  getDashboardId(dashboardName: string): string {
    ...
  }

  getWidgetInfo(dashboardName: string, widgetName: string): ISisenseWidget {
   ...
   return widgetInfo;
  }
}
```

I've written the test file but She is not OK with it. Please help me what exactly my tech lead is asking for. Feel free to ask for more code details.

Comment: Why would you use a for loop instead of an forEach?

Comment: Ok. I'll make it `forEach`.

Comment: I'm editing my question. I'll keep my code as minimum as possible.

Comment: But where exactly is your test?

Comment: I would help you but I am having difficulty reading `getDataFromWidget` function. What I would suggest for you is to do this class, it is amazing and you will learn Angular Unit testing in a good way. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/unit-testing-angular/table-of-contents. Create a free trial.

Comment: @AliF50, I'm following that only. I'm following AAA concept of testing by Joe Eames and some lectures of Deborah Kurata. By the way I've purchased 1 year subscription. :-)

Comment: @AliF50, Ok. Let me create a stackblitz for the same. Give me some time please.

Comment: @Tanzeel Take a look at my answer and let me know if it helped/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help you

```
describe('FilterPanelComponent', () => {
    let component: FilterBarComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterBarComponent>;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                FilterBarComponent
            ],
            imports: [],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: SisenseService,
                    useClass: SisenseServiceStub
                },
                SisenseConfigService
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterBarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should call getDataFromWidget() on init method',()=>{
        spyOn(component,'getDataFromWidget').and.callThrough();
        component.ngOnInit();
        expect(component.getDataFromWidget).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

    it('getDataFromWidget should set selected member count',()=>{
        component.selectedMembersCount = 0;
        component.getDataFromWidget();
        expect(component.selectedMembersCount).toEqual(1);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const htmlEle  = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#some-count'); // For class try query(By.css('.some-count')).nativeElement;
        expect(htmlEle.innerHTML).toBe(1);        
    })
});

// this is the stub she is talking about
export class SisenseServiceStub{
    getWidgetData(){
        return of({
            queryResult : {
                value : {
                    data : 1
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Few months back, I also saw some of my juniors struggling with unit tests. So, I wrote [series of articles which can help you as well](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7).

Give it a try and let me know if it helped. [Here is how you play with stubs and spies](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49)

Comment: I can wait to try this. I'll get back to you Sir. :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel : Cool, do let me know if you any further questions

Comment: Sir this much was enough for me. From here I can take control. Thanks for the artricles. I'll share with my fellow interns. :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel : Happy to help you :) Feel free to leave some claps on those as well ;)

Comment: Sir can you please answer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474540/how-to-exclude-spec-files-while-getting-code-coverage-angular

Comment: @Tanzeel : I have provided the answer. Sorry for the late reply :) CHeers